# How to find the minimum value of c?

Tags: self-study, random-variable

[image: How to find the answer of question (iii) of example 5.2?]

In this book, the answer is not clear. What will be the method to find the value of c?

Comment: You're asked to indicate your thinking so far. With no effort at a solution, a post like this will be closed.

Comment: Substitute $k$ into the pmf and compute $P(X\leq x)$; it should take a few seconds in your head to find the first $x$ that satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the book, the answer is reached through trial and error.

So, first we take c=1 and calculate P(X<=1):

P(X<=1) = P(X=0) + P(X=1) = 0 + 1/10 = 0.1

Then, we take c=2 and calculate P(X<=2):

P(X<=2) = P(X=0) + P(X=1) + P(X=2) = 0 + 1/10 + 2/10 = 3/10 = 0.3

Then, we take c=3 and calculate P(X<=3):

P(X<=3) = P(X=0) + P(X=1) + P(X=2) + P(X=3) = 0 + 1/10 + 2/10 + 2/10 = 5/10 = 0.5

Then, we take c=4 and calculate P(X<=4):

P(X<=4) = P(X=0) + P(X=1) + P(X=2) + P(X=3) + P(X=4) = 0 + 1/10 + 2/10 + 2/10 +3/10 = 8/10 = 0.8

So, for c=4 we can see that P(X<=4) < 0.5